# grails file download

Tags: file, grails, download

I have sucessfully managed to make a file upload system which basically is copying files to a specific folder and save in the database its location. Now i need help with the download part. Imagine my file location is: **Files/1306242602661_file1.exe**, and in my view i have this:

```
<g:link controller="fileManager" action="downloadFile">
     Download</g:link><br>
```

I need help with the downloadFile controller. Could you please give me a hint about how to do this, considering my filename is a string:

String fileName = "Files/1306242602661_file1.exe"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Within your controller create an download action with following content:

```
def file = new File("path/to/file")

if (file.exists()) {
   response.setContentType("application/octet-stream")
   response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "filename=${file.name}")
   response.outputStream << file.bytes
   return
}
// else for err message
```

Comment: I didn't tried your solution, but having a doubt. What is the need to setup contentType and header their..? For any security issue?

Comment: Yes: Tell the browser that your output is binary and the filename for download:

Comment: In case your file name contains spaces the filename parameter value needs to be quoted like this: response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "filename=\"${file.name}\"")

Answer (score 7):

You can render a file. see http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/ref/Controllers/render.html

```
render file: new File ("path/to/file.pdf"), fileName: 'myPdfFile.pdf'
```

Comment: You may have to add the "contentType" attribute to the renderer.