# create file in memory and let user download

Tags: grails, text, download

I am coming from razor in asp.net.  Usually I would use a [FilePost] for this, but not sure how to do it in grails.  Here is the situation

I have a controller

```
class MyController{
def index{ }
}
```

I then have a link on index in the form of

```
<g:link controller="MyController" action="downloadFile">Download</g:link><br>
```

What I want this to do is take a string (doesn't matter what it is) and I want it to prompt the user to download a text file containing that string.  Thanks!

Comment: See similar question with answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111255/grails-file-download.

Comment: I saw that one, but that takes a file that already exists and downloads it, I want to make a file on the fly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working Solution:

```
def downloadFile =
{
    File file = File.createTempFile("temp",".txt")
    file.write("hello world!")
    response.setHeader "Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=${file.name}.txt"
    response.contentType = 'text-plain'
    response.outputStream << file.text
    response.outputStream.flush()
}
```

Comment: See my post, you don't have to create a file

Answer (score 4):

So probably something like this:

```
byte[] bytes = "string".bytes

response.setContentType("text/plain")
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "filename=\"xyz.txt\"")
response.setContentLength(bytes.size())
response.outputStream << bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

What is preventing you from creating the bytes yourself and feeding it to the outputstream? String.getbytes or bytes created from a business method of yours for example.

Answer (score 0):

In header again .txt file extension is not required.